# Library to edit odt documents in php

Tags: php, editing, odf, opendocument

I try to edit ODT-documents programmaticly in PHP. In fact I just want to do some text replacement and adding new rows in a table.

I know that a normal ODF document is an archive containing XML-files. But before I reinvent the wheel: is there any library which does most of the tasks? Or should I just parse the XML-file in a DOM-parser and modify it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument_software lists several PHP tools for working with ODT.

- [Docvert](http://docvert.org/)
- [OpenDocumentPHP](http://www.opendocumentphp.org/)
- [odf-xslt](http://www.jejik.com/odf-xslt/)
- [OpenDocument](http://pear.php.net/package/OpenDocument)
- [ods-php](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ods-php/)
- [odtPHP](http://www.odtphp.com/)

I haven't used any of these, I'm just giving you the list.  You'll have to evaluate them to see if they have the specific features you need.

Comment: The last one looks very promising (it's always the last in a list that is the most interesting). According to the tutorial text-replacement and row-adding is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I also suggest that you also try with [OpenTBS](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php).
It is able to edit an OpenDocument file using the technical of templates, but it can also retrieve XML in an OpenDocument.

Comment: OpenTDB is not maintained since 2006 and the demo don't work anymore!

Comment: @Florito : OpenTBS last version dated 2013-08-30. There is a beta actually on the road, and the forum is active. So where did you see that it is not maintained ?

Comment: can we open an ODF document in browser and then save using OpenTBS

Comment: @Umair Ayub: OpenTBS is under PHP and PHP is a server side process.

Comment: OpenTBS is used to merge documents! I want an editor~